# PyDev with Virtualenv: Interpreter not found

Tags: python, virtualenv, pydev

I am having trouble getting PyDev to work with Virtualenv. I have:

1. Created a PyDev project. At that point I am forced to specify an interpreter, so I choose the installed system Python 2.7 interpreted. When I add the interpreter the necessary library folders are added as well.
2. Issued `virtualenv venv` in the project directory to create a Virtualenv environment.
3. Removed the standard interpreter I added in the first step and tried to add the one located in my `venv` directory. But I can not seem to get it to work.

**In more detail:**

**All directories in my PythonFlaskTemplate PyDev project:**
[image: All directories in my PythonFlaskTemplate PyDev project]

**The result when I try to add the interpreter in my `venv` directory as well as the necessary libraries there. Did I miss any library directory which I should have picked? Did I pick a directory I should not have picked?**
[image: The result of configuring my Python interpreter]

**And I still get an error saying that it can not find an interpreter. Even though the interpreter path I picked is correct (I can start it by `./venv/bin/python2.7`):**
[image: Error: Interpreter not found]

**How should I configure PyDev to make it play nicely with Virtualenv?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem there seems to be that you configured your project not to use the 'default' interpreter, but to use an interpreter which has to be named 'python'.

You can fix that by changing the name of the interpreter in the interpreter preferences (i.e.: preferences > pydev > interpreters > python interpreter > double click it and type 'python')

Or you can set your project to use the default interpreter (i.e.: select project > alt + enter > pydev - interpreter/grammar > interpreter: Default).

Comment: Thanks for the great PyDev! I'll support you by buying LiClipse as soon as my budget allows (also, it looks really nice, I am not a fan of the std Eclipse UI). I will try your suggestion!

Comment: By the way. Is this how you would start a new PyDev project which uses Virtualenv: Create PyDev project, Create Virtualenv, Change settings to use Virtualenv? Or do you have a better alternative? I am new to Virtualenv, but it seems nice. :)

Comment: It worked! I feel a bit daft not thinking about it myself, but that is how I am sometimes. :) Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! (I don't have enough rep. to vote up, I will do it when I am allowed to.)

Comment: Great! Now, as far as PyDev is concerned, a virtualenv is just another regular Python install (so, what you're doing is fine)... personally currently I'm using conda a bit more than virtualenv (although I usually don't really create a new env for each project and usually just use the default interpreter for all projects -- but many times I have many projects from source and configure each separately and reference one from another to make up my dependencies instead of putting libraries in the interpreter).